# Memory leak for Optuna trial with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, optuna

#### The Background

I have a machine learning pipeline that consists of `N` boosted models (LGBMRegressor), each with identical hyperparameters.  Each of the `N` LGBMRegressors is trained on a separate chunk of data.  My current workstation has a lot of cores, so I multiprocess each regressor on a separate thread.

#### The Problem

I am trying to tune the parameters that go into the LGBMRegressors through optuna.  When I use the multiprocessing inside an optuna trial, it has a memory leak and I run out of memory.  **Can I use multiprocessing inside an optuna trial and not run into a memory leak?**

#### Minimal Reproducible Example

```
import optuna
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
from lightgbm import LGBMRegressor

N = 500
n_cores = 30
rows_per_N = 1000
cols_per_N=50
data = [ [np.random.normal(size=(rows_per_N, cols_per_N)), np.random.normal(size=(rows_per_N, ))] for i in range(N)]

def get_metric(data):
    (X, y), params = data
    model =LGBMRegressor(**params)
    model.fit(X, y)
    return np.abs( model.predict(X) - y )


def objective(trial):
    param = {
        "n_jobs": "1",
        "num_leaves": trial.suggest_int("num_leaves", 2, 256)
    }
    lgb_params = [param for _ in range(N)]
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(n_cores)
    results = p.map(get_metric, zip(data,lgb_params))
    return np.mean(results)


study = optuna.create_study(direction="minimize")
study.optimize(objective, n_trials=100)
```

#### Alternative Solutions

I have written the above code as a `for` loop and it has not had memory issues.  The drawback here is that this is 30x slower than the multiprocessed solution.